# UWP how to refresh text without re-navigate

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, multilingual

I have a multi language application that allow user to switch language using dropdown menu. It works fine, but it is too slow when switching the language because I need to re-navigate to my current frame. This is because I need to reload my products (which takes a bit of time).

Here is my code:

```
 var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(sLang);
 Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();

 Frame.Navigate(Frame.CurrentSourcePageType);  //I want to avoid this as calling this will re-initialize my page - which in turn re-load my products
```

My question is, is there a way to force all component with **x:Uid** to reload from resource file (eg. **Strings/en-US/Resources.resw**) without calling **Frame.Navigate()**?

In WinForm, I can do something like:

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
{
    rm.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
}
```

Is there any equivalent in UWP? Or is there any better way to tackle my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm interested too.

Comment: Yes, but it is *sort of* a manual process. I created a base class which has override function `ReloadLang()`. Once the language is changed (via the dropdown), I manually call this `ReloadLang()` for each control and reload the text. That is why I didn't post it as an answer in the hope that someone will come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this pattern from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) which uses [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/tree/master/DemoApps/QuizGame) to notify a change in my data. If im not wrong, you want to notify the xaml element's content(e.g. Text) when it changes. Then you need to use binding.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried not to use the binding because (first) I need to create a class then load all string resources to that class and then bind it. But on language change, I need to somehow notify the changes. It will take huge amount of changes to my code. Therefore, my question is how to force the component to reload from resource file.

Comment: Dont think so, you have to implement once the 'INotifyPropertyChanged' and you are ready.Then you will just change the values to use a different resource from a viewmodel and you are done!

Comment: yes, I know that. I have considered using binding, but I'll need to change lots in my code. I prefer the answer stick with my question. I have all my GUI components with x:Uid. I just simply need to force refresh the GUI.